# Ideas about how to create a splash screen using PyGObject?

Tags: python-3.x, splash-screen, pygobject

Any ideas about how to create a splash screen for my application using Python3 and PyGObject ?
For example : Like the GIMP's slpash screen. 
In my case, i used time.sleep(...) and it makes my application start very slowly. I'm wondering if should i thread the slpash screen Gui. 
I've searched in websites and i didn't find any solution.
Thanks for your answers. And sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. create a window
2. will it with your content
3. open it
4. force it to show
5. set a timeout to close said window at a later time
6. proceed with initialisation

There are examples out there, e.g. http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577919-splash-screen-gtk/